# Why is this flex item taking more than it's correct width?

Tags: css

I am making an app for getting real-time gold prices

The problem is design-related, which is that Karat's prices are less wide than the select item and ounce price width but I want them the same width. What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Thanks very much in advance.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');

.title-bg-color {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #d7c18b, #e9a522);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

:root,
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #302d2d);
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.main-panel {
    background-color: #DCD9CD;
    min-height: 75vh;
    width: 75vw;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.main-panel > h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #020202;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 3rem;
}



.select-container {
    display: flex;
}

.select-container > label {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 16px;
}
.select-container > #currency {
    flex: 3;
    color: #000;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.oz {
    display: flex;
}

.oz .oz-title {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 16px;
}

.oz .oz-price {
    background-color: #282222;
    flex: 3;
    padding: 16px;
}



.gram {
    display: flex;
}

.gram > .title {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 16px;
}

.gram > .list {
    flex: 3;
}


.gram > .list > .list-item {
    color: #3b3333;
    padding: 16px;
}

.k24 {
    background-color: #f5d000;
}
.k21 {
    background-color: #e0bf00;
}
.k18 {
    background-color: #ccad00;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-panel">
<h1>Real-Time Gold Price</h1>
    <div class="select-container">
        <label for="currency" class="title-bg-color">Choose Currency</label>
        <select name="currency" id="currency">
            <option value="usa">USA</option>
            <option value="uae">UAE</option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="oz">
        <div class="oz-title title-bg-color">Ounce:</div>
        <div class="oz-price">1751.22</div>
    </div>

    <div class="gram">
        <div class="title-bg-color title">Gram: </div>
        <div class="list">
            <div class="k24 list-item">24 Karat: 11 </div>
            <div class="k21 list-item">21 Karat: 12 </div>
            <div class="k18 list-item">18 Karat: 13 </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Very much appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to the padding applied to `oz-price` that is not opplied to `list` (it's applied to its child instead). To rectify this move the padding to list and rectify it with negative margin

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');

.title-bg-color {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #d7c18b, #e9a522);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

:root,
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #302d2d);
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.main-panel {
    background-color: #DCD9CD;
    min-height: 75vh;
    width: 75vw;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.main-panel > h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #020202;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 3rem;
}



.select-container {
    display: flex;
}

.select-container > label {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 16px;
}
.select-container > #currency {
    flex: 3;
    color: #000;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.oz {
    display: flex;
}

.oz .oz-title {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 16px;
}

.oz .oz-price {
    background-color: #282222;
    flex: 3;
    padding: 16px;
}



.gram {
    display: flex;
}

.gram > .title {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 16px;
}

.gram > .list {
    flex: 3;
    padding:0 16px;
}


.gram > .list > .list-item {
    color: #3b3333;
    padding: 16px;
    margin:0 -16px
}

.k24 {
    background-color: #f5d000;
}
.k21 {
    background-color: #e0bf00;
}
.k18 {
    background-color: #ccad00;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-panel">
<h1>Real-Time Gold Price</h1>
    <div class="select-container">
        <label for="currency" class="title-bg-color">Choose Currency</label>
        <select name="currency" id="currency">
            <option value="usa">USA</option>
            <option value="uae">UAE</option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="oz">
        <div class="oz-title title-bg-color">Ounce:</div>
        <div class="oz-price">1751.22</div>
    </div>

    <div class="gram">
        <div class="title-bg-color title">Gram: </div>
        <div class="list">
            <div class="k24 list-item">24 Karat: 11 </div>
            <div class="k21 list-item">21 Karat: 12 </div>
            <div class="k18 list-item">18 Karat: 13 </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why padding the list children is different from padding the parent? I really can't get it!

Comment: @WaelAssaf it's not a parent child relation. list don't have padding while oz-price have. This is making the difference in the flex calculation. Adding the same padding to list will fix the issue (then we need to rectify inside the child items)

Comment: Flex calculations are being affected! I get it!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that, while `.gram > .title` has 16px of padding, the list `.gram > .list` doesn't have any.

This causes the title to take up more space than the list. In order to reduce this space, you can remove some padding of the title:

```css
.gram > .title {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 16px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
```

Final result:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');

.title-bg-color {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #d7c18b, #e9a522);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

:root,
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #302d2d);
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.main-panel {
    background-color: #DCD9CD;
    min-height: 75vh;
    width: 75vw;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.main-panel > h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #020202;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 3rem;
}



.select-container {
    display: flex;
}

.select-container > label {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 16px;
}
.select-container > #currency {
    flex: 3;
    color: #000;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.oz {
    display: flex;
}

.oz .oz-title {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 16px;
}

.oz .oz-price {
    background-color: #282222;
    flex: 3;
    padding: 16px;
}



.gram {
    display: flex;
}

.gram > .title {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 16px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}

.gram > .list {
    flex: 3;
}


.gram > .list > .list-item {
    color: #3b3333;
    padding: 16px;
}

.k24 {
    background-color: #f5d000;
}
.k21 {
    background-color: #e0bf00;
}
.k18 {
    background-color: #ccad00;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-panel">
<h1>Real-Time Gold Price</h1>
    <div class="select-container">
        <label for="currency" class="title-bg-color">Choose Currency</label>
        <select name="currency" id="currency">
            <option value="usa">USA</option>
            <option value="uae">UAE</option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="oz">
        <div class="oz-title title-bg-color">Ounce:</div>
        <div class="oz-price">1751.22</div>
    </div>

    <div class="gram">
        <div class="title-bg-color title">Gram: </div>
        <div class="list">
            <div class="k24 list-item">24 Karat: 11 </div>
            <div class="k21 list-item">21 Karat: 12 </div>
            <div class="k18 list-item">18 Karat: 13 </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```